# How to get row values by selecting checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/146/) each check box is having id and its obtained from the json.There is a drop down also corresponding to each row

now suppose I have selected 1st and last row 
then checkboxes values are 1 and 3

when the check box is selected then only the drop down menu will be enabled.
Now from the 1st row ,I have selected the text from the drop down menu and from the last row I have selected option and after that when I click save then it should return me `1:text,3,option` so that I will pass it to server and do the necessary processing.The way I did gives me only 1,2

```
console.log($(".cd:checked").map(function () {return this.value;}).get().join(","));
```

Comment: I'm having such a hard time trying to read you're question....can you get straight to the point? I'm 99.99% sure all that code is totally irrelevant

Comment: @Leo all the codes are inter related.

Comment: @Leo see the rows are dynamically generated that I get from ajax json.If select a checkbox then only the drop down will enable.Now when I clcik the save option button I want the id and menu in comma separated.Hope you understood nnow

Comment: The id of what? Do you mean the checkbox's value? Does "menu" = "dropdown item"? I still don't understand how you justify this output...`1:text,3,option`...where does `:` come from? Where does `option` come from? Are you sober?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding of the question, here is a solution. Let me know if it solves the problem.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/Wy22s/148/)**

```
$('#addNew tr').each(function(index,element){
    if($(this).find('.cd').prop('checked')){
        key=$(this).find('.cd').val();
        value=$(this).find('.QSelect').val();
        newObject.push(key + ":" + value);
    } 
});
```

With the Good, Average & Poor checkbox selections. **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/Wy22s/150/)**

```
$('#addNew tr').each(function(index,element){
    if($(this).find('.cd').prop('checked')){
        key=$(this).find('.cd').val();
        value=$(this).find('.QSelect').val();
        var options=[];
        $(this).find('.checkbox-inline input').each(function(i,e){
            if($(this).prop('checked')){
                options.push($(this).parents('label').text());
            }
        });
        newObject.push(key + ":" + value + ":" + options.join(','));
    } 
});
```